# Devise: How to quickly reset all user passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, devise

I have a rake task which (among other things) clones my production database to my local machine and resets all the users passwords to `password` (or whatever).

My current implementation looks something like:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user.password = 'password'
  user.save
end
```

And that works fine. But now that we have over 1000 users it's getting pretty slow, and it's sure to get worse.

**EDIT**

Okay. Here's a partial answer:

```
Devise.stretches = 1
User.find_each do |user|
  user.password = 'password'
  user.save
end
Devise.stretches = 10
```

This got me about a 5-10x speed increase. While it's still probably slow compared to a SQL-based solution, it's still a very nice improvement. This should scale to at least 10,000 users.

I may still mess around with a SQL solution, if I have time.

I'll leave this question open for a bit. If someone else has a better solution, please post.

#### Final Answer / Best Solution

As several comments have suggested, the fastest solution is to execute a mass update via SQL. Devise now allows you to set the `encrypted_password` directly:

```
sample_user = User.last
sample_user.password = "password"
encrypted_password = sample_user.encrypted_password
User.update_all(encrypted_password: encrypted_password)
```

Basically, we set the password on a single user, then we can use their `encrypted_password` to execute a mass update. This solution should scale to virtually any number of users.

*Credit to @vladCovaliov for suggesting this solution in a comment below.*

Comment: How slow it is?( Have you measured? e.g. xxx ms ) as far as I know, `find_each` method is typical used for your scenario, and its "default batch size" is 1000, so I am wondering it should match your needs.

Comment: It's not the lookup that's slowing it down - `find_each` is fine. It's the process of reseting the actual password. AFAIK, Devise is doing some encryption and whatnot, and that's what takes time. Each password takes about 1/2 second to reset. Again, not a huge deal now. But already mildly annoying and getting worse everyday.

Comment: I see, then I suggest you execute the raw SQL rather than ActiveRecord, and you have to get a encrypted password according to the salt( all the salt in 1000 records must be the same).

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would say write the sql you want, e.g.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(' update users set encrypted_password = 'password')
```

However usually the password is encrypted and you directly encrypt it using MD5 or an authorization/authentication mechanism such as Devise or Authlogic.  In that case you actually create or change a password by passing in password and password confirmation values (when creating the record in Rails) that must match.  If they do match then the password is encrypted and actually stored in the database.  For these reason, this has to be done one-by-one unless you use a hashing algorithm in your direct sql.

It may be as simple as

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(' update users set password = md5('password'))
```

Comment: Hm. This doesn't work as written. Right out of the gate, Devise doesn't actually have a column called `password`. It has columns for `encrypted_password` and `password_salt`. Nevertheless, I'll toy with the ideas suggested and see what comes out of it. We see if I have any good ideas. Thanks!

Comment: yes, updated.  Note that I had said 'normally, but...'.  Updated with more emphasis.

Comment: If you do something like this using md5 devise will raise an error on login. Instead you can manually update the password for one user, call encrypted_password to see the encrypted version, and using the first call you can easily update all the passwords to the encrypted version => all users will have the same password.

Comment: @vladCovaliov I just tried your suggestion and it works perfectly! If you want to post an official answer, I will mark it as correct. If I don't hear from you in a few days, I'll circle back and update my question to include your advice. Just want to give you the chance to earn some much deserved cred.